# Setting up a domain name

Tags: domains, dns

I am trying to point a domain of `support.example.com` to a public IP address and am not sure how I can achieve this. I have tried a CNAME record but I understand that it's not possible to direct a CNAME to an IP address.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add an A record. To point a sub domain, access the zone file for domain.com and add the A record for support to point to a IP address. Instead of using the CNAME record, use A record. The entry should look like below.

support    14400   IN      A       xx.xx.xx.xx

Replace xx.xx.xx.xx with actual server IP.

You can set a A record from the registrar panel as well.

If you are using the Name servers that point to your server, you have to add the A record from the server. If the Name servers are that provided by the registrar, you have to do it from the registrar panel.